# getting values from strings taken by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to get values from strings.

```
<div class="example">sth 44.05 $</div>

<div class="example">sth another 140.00 $</div>

<div class="example">sth sth 100.05 $</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>
<p id="values">demo</p>
```

If it's one, it's simple:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelector('.example').innerText;

let number=x.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0];

document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = +number;

}</script>
```

But I'm not sure how to get all those values (and then count them). Trying to do to sth similar, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerText;
} 


var value = [];
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    value.push( x[i].innerText);
} 


let number=value.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0];

document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = +number;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let number=value.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0];
```

`match` is a method you find on strings.

`value` is an array, not a string.

You'll need to convert `value` to a string (e.g. with `join`) if you want to run a regex across all of it.